# How can I make an object change direction?

Tags: c#, unity

I have a moving cube that, when it moves over an arrow, should change its direction to the direction of that arrow. What would I need to do in order to accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: Is this question about detecting intersection with the arrows or about changing the cube's movement angle? How is each arrow storing its angle?

Comment: I want to create a simple code motion 

I just want my cube to detect the arrow and start moving in the direction it indicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how much arrows you have, you could simply check the distance from the arrows center to the cubes center and do something if it is below a threshhold.

```
//I assume ARROWS to hold the Transform of all arrows
foreach ( Transform arrow in ARROWS)
{
    if ( (arrow.position - cube.position).magnitude  <= (Time.fixedDeltaTime * cube.speed) / 2)
        cube.changeDirection (arrow.direction);
        break;
}
```

This will ensure, that the cube moves as close as possible to an arrow before changing direction.

**ATTENTION:**
I totally made up the fields `speed`, `changeDirection ()` and `direction`. You have to define them yourself or derive them from the existing data.

The best place for this would most likely be the `fixedUpdate()` of your cube.